# Running PerfView in production environment

Tags: .net, performance, perfview

I want to run PerfView -> Collect with default CPU Sample Interval on the production server for some time. Also, I want to take Take Heap Snapshot to check memory leak. Is it a good decision or not? How can it impact server resources and responsiveness of server application?

Comment: Several links/articles on the internet suggest it should be at least "tolerable". In the end it depends on your specific setup and needs, i.e. if you have no other chance or environment to reproduce the issues you need to investigate. Oh, and I think for a "heap snapshot" you don't have to have it running "for some time" (as in collecting data), just take the snapshot and be good with it. So impact should be minimal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, for some time it's only about Collect.